# Using Persistent Flash Message Library for ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, railo, lucee

I am trying to use a library for showing `Flash Messages` https://github.com/elpete/flashmessage But I am having trouble getting it working correctly. The documentation isn't that great and I am new to ColdFusion. I want to have the ability to have persistent error messages across pages. Specifically during checkout so when the user needs to go back or a validation error occurs the message will appear. According to the documentation:

> The FlashMessage.cfc needs three parameters to work:
>
> A reference to your flash storage object. This object will need
>   get(key) and put(key, value) methods. A config object with the
>   following properties: A unique flashKey name to avoid naming
>   conflicts. A reference to your containerTemplatePath. This is the view
>   that surrounds each of the individual messages. It will have
>   references to a flashMessages array and your messageTemplatePath. A
>   reference to your messageTemplatePath. This is the view that
>   represents a single message in FlashMessage. It will have a reference
>   to a single flash message. The name is chosen by you in your container
>   template. Create your object with your two parameters and then use it
>   as normal.

I am getting the error

```
the function getMessages has an invalid return value , can't cast null value to value of type [array]
```

I had this script somewhat working at one point but it seems very finicky. I believe it is my implementation of it. I am hoping someone here can help me figure out where I went wrong. Or give me some pointers because I am not sure I am even implementing it correctly.

This is What I have in my testing script:

```
<cfscript>

    alertStorage = createObject("component", 'alert');

    config = {
        flashKey = "myCustomFlashKey",
        containerTemplatePath = "/flashmessage/views/_templates/FlashMessageContainer.cfm",
        messageTemplatePath = "/flashmessage/views/_templates/FlashMessage.cfm"    
    };

    flash = new flashmessage.models.FlashMessage(alertStorage, config);
    flash.message('blah');
    flash.danger('boom');


</cfscript>
```

And inside of alert.cfc I have:

```
component {

    public any function get(key) {
        for(var i = 1; i < ArrayLen(session[key]); i++) {
            return session[key][i];
        }
    }

    public any function put(key, value) {
        ArrayAppend(session.myCustomFlashKey, value);
        return true;
    }

    public any function exists() {
        if(structKeyExists(session,"myCustomFlashKey")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            session.myCustomFlashKey = ArrayNew();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Flash Message Component looks like this:

```
component name="FlashMessage" singleton {

    /**
     * @flashStorage.inject coldbox:flash
     * @config.inject coldbox:setting:flashmessage
     */
    public FlashMessage function init(any flashStorage, any config) {
        instance.flashKey = arguments.config.flashKey;

        singleton.flashStorage = arguments.flashStorage;
        instance.containerTemplatePath = arguments.config.containerTemplatePath;
        instance.messageTemplatePath = arguments.config.messageTemplatePath;

        // Initialize our flash messages to an empty array if it hasn't ever been created
        if (! singleton.flashStorage.exists(instance.flashKey)) {
            setMessages([]);
        }

        return this;
    }


    public void function message(required string text, string type = "default") {
        appendMessage({ message: arguments.text, type = arguments.type });
    }

    public any function onMissingMethod(required string methodName, required struct methodArgs) {
        message(methodArgs[1], methodName);
    }

    public any function render() {
        var flashMessages = getMessages();
        var flashMessageTemplatePath = instance.messageTemplatePath;
        savecontent variable="messagesHTML" {
            include "#instance.containerTemplatePath#";
        }

        setMessages([]);

        return messagesHTML;
    }

    public array function getMessages() {
        return singleton.flashStorage.get(instance.flashKey, []);
    }

    private void function setMessages(required array messages) {
        singleton.flashStorage.put(
            name  = instance.flashKey,
            value = arguments.messages
        );
    }

    private void function appendMessage(required struct message) {
        var currentMessages = getMessages();
        ArrayAppend(currentMessages, arguments.message);
        setMessages(currentMessages);
    }



}
```

Comment: That's more code than I'm willing to muddle through.  However, the error message tells you what's wrong.  Isolate the applicable function and find out why you are getting a null value.  Then decide what to do about it.